# Trying to log in my EC2 server, but port 22 : connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terminal

I don't know what's wrong with it. Here is a screenshot.

(first image is what i've done in terminal to log in my EC2 server
 second image is what i've set in "System preference --> sharing --> remote login)

Yosemite is my OS. Please help me,

[image]

Comment: A brief comment is in order, here, about security groups, since we have two answers so far invoking that: *the problem is somewhere else.*  Security group settings *cannot* cause "connection refused."  They can only cause "connection timed out."  Security groups *discard* traffic that is not authorized.  They do not reject it.

Comment: Is this a new server? Has this *ever* worked for you?  Have you confirmed, in the console, that this address/hostname is still correct, and that the instance is showing healthy?

Comment: No, i worked 3 months ago. What you said is that it is not related with Security group. But how can i confirm whether address/hostname is correct and instance is showing healthy? I'm almost novice, so i would be glad if u explain in detaill. thanks.

Comment: Security group settings can break any kind of connection, but the failure/error message will look different.  Address/hostname, health status, etc. are under "ec2" and "instances" in the AWS console.  I suspect your instance either has a different IP address and hostname, or it may need to be rebooted to recover from some kind of failure or manual error, but there is not yet enough information available.

Comment: Michael is correct about Security Group. Are your extra sure you're trying to open connect to the correct IP address? Remember that IP addresses changes at each start / stop

Comment: In case you are 300% sure about the IP address, it looks like no daemon is accepting your incoming connection. Maybe a simple reboot of the instance might solve this. Reboot, at the opposite of a stop/start, Does not change the underlying IP address

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the right key file, you could be running into some security settings issues. Check your security group and make sure that the server is accepting connections on port 22 from all addresses. Also, I generally use the IP address when SSHing into an EC2 box instead of a url, as it is much shorter and more concise. Also, make sure that your server is running Ubuntu. I know that different OS's on EC2 use different default usernames.
Your default username can be found at this page:
http://alestic.com/2014/01/ec2-ssh-username

In the end, your ssh command should be something like 
ssh -i otkey.pem [username for your os]@[ip of your box]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right command for an ubuntu server.  Check to make sure that security groups are configured and that you don't have Network Access Control Lists configured on your VPC.  The configuration you made to the settings of your laptop are to open it up for people to log into your laptop, they don't do anything to facilitate you connecting out.

Comment: I have two security groups, which are "default" and what i've made. And i set inbound port range : 22 and source : anyware. If you don't mind i want to show screeshot of my security group via email.

Comment: Sure, send me an email.  My email is my last name at my last name .com.  Also send a screen shot of your NACLs.